# How to implement Advanced ExtentReports Logic for Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, extentreports

I am looking for a way to implement Advanced ExtentReports with Test Steps and Results Data beyond the Basic Setup.

I currently have a working ExtentReports report and am looking for a way to implement and display test steps using the ExtentReports (Logger) class. I have tried adding (Logger.log) statements to my classes but am unable to view the test steps in my ExtentReports file.

```java
public static WebDriver driver;
public static ExtentReports extentReports;
public static ExtentTest extentTest;
public static ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
public static ExtentTest test;
public static ExtentTest logger;

@BeforeSuite
public void beforeSuite(){
         htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(new File(("reports/Test Automation Report.html")));
         htmlReporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("extent-config.xml"));
         extentReports=new ExtentReports();
         extentReports.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
         extentReports.setSystemInfo("Environment", "QA");
         htmlReporter.config().setChartVisibilityOnOpen(true);
         htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("AutomationTesting.in Demo Report");
         htmlReporter.config().setReportName("My Own Report");
         htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.TOP);
         htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.DARK);
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void before(Method method) {
        extentTest=extentReports.createTest(method.getName().toString());
        driver = DriverType.chromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        IRISBase base = new IRISBase(driver);
        base.fmaLoad();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void getResult(ITestResult result) throws Exception {
        if (driver!=null){
            System.out.println("deleteAllCookies");
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            }

        if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE)
        {
            System.out.println(">>>Test Failed"); //Which Test Failed and Why (Method Name Output)
            extentTest.log(Status.FAIL,  MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName() + " Test case FAILED due to below issues:", ExtentColor.RED));
            extentTest.fail(result.getThrowable());
            System.out.println("Automation Test Run: " + result.getMethod().toString()); //Testing and Results (Relevant)
        }
        else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS)
        {
            System.out.println(">>>Test Passed");
            extentTest.log(Status.PASS, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName() + " Test Case PASSED", ExtentColor.GREEN));
            logger.info(MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName() + " Test Case PASSED", ExtentColor.GREEN));
            System.out.println("====================================================================================================="); 
            System.out.println("Automation Test Run: " + result.getMethod().toString()); //Testing and Results
            System.out.println("=====================================================================================================");
        }
        else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP)
        {
            System.out.println(">>>Test Skipped");
            extentTest.log(Status.SKIP, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName() + " Test Case SKIPPED", ExtentColor.BLUE));
            System.out.println("Automation Test Run: " + result.getMethod().toString()); //Testing and Results
        }

        if(driver!=null) {
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        }
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void testComplete() {
        extentReports.flush();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.quit();
    }

    private static File fileWithDirectoryAssurance(String directory, String filename) {

        Date date = new Date() ;
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss") ;

        File dir = new File(directory);
        if (!dir.exists()) dir.mkdirs();
        return new File(directory + "/" + filename);
    }
}
```

**Expected ExtentReports file**
[image: Expected ExtentReports file]

**Actual ExtentReports file**
[image: Actual ExtentReports file]

Comment: See here for Screenshot 1: (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RfAqCGvy1z3E_n9WgLNJqWkUKV5RAqdH/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: See here for Screenshot 2: (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uVWMn-hzAMZFYZkKMuvQlTu3s5RcKMZ9/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Use object of ExtentTest for logging Example:
Note:change your @aftermethod

```
    public static ExtentReports extent;
    public static ExtentTest logger;
    @BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true)
    public void config(){
        extent = new ExtentReports(path, true);
        extent.addSystemInfo("Host Name", System.getProperty("user.name"));
        extent.addSystemInfo("Environment", "API Testing");
        extent.loadConfig(new File(XMLPath));}

   @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void getResult(ITestResult result) {
    if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
        logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Test case is passed " + result.getName());

    } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
        logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Test case is failed " + result.getName());
        logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Test case is failed " + result.getThrowable());
    } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
        logger.log(LogStatus.SKIP, "Test case is Skiped " + result.getName());
    }
    extent.endTest(logger);
}

@AfterSuite(alwaysRun = true)
public void endReport() {
    extent.flush();
    // SendEmail.Email(ReportPath);
    extent.close();
    log.setinstanceNull();
}
```

Use ExtentTest object to log test steps in test cases import the base class and use object of ExtentTest like this
Sample test case

```
logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, message);
logger.log(LogStatus.ERROR, message);
```

To get the list of test cases before starting a test case use extent.startTest method where extent is object of ExtentReports

```
@Test(groups = { "sanityuserfolw" })
public void testcase() {

    logger = extent.startTest("TestCase Name", "test case summary");



    resp = part_study.sampletest(input);
    logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "response is "+resp.getStatusCode());
    assertEquals(resp.getStatusCode(), 200, "Error in adding study " + resp.statusLine());

}
```